# Why Child Protection service tell Lyla to wait for 6 months to fill the form?

Tags: plot-explanation, august-rush

In August Rush (2007), Lyla is searching for her son Evan so she approach help from Child Protection Service , but they tell her to wait for about **6 months** to fill the form.

> Richard Jeffries: You fill out a couple forms.
>
> Lyla:  No, no, **six months**, they said. I don't have **six months** for forms.
>
> Richard Jeffries: Then, I can't help you there.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: hi, I clarify my question. now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what they are referencing. At least in the US, most child protective services are underfunded and overwhelmed, and it takes a long time for them to be able to investigate certain cases.

In this case, I believe they are telling her that once she fills out the forms, it will be 6 months wait after that point, not that they are telling her to wait 6 months before filling out the forms.